# How to hover reciprocally on different elements with jquery.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I'm trying to make it so that when you hover a list item, the corresponding piece is highlighted, and when you hover the piece, the corresponding list item is highlighted.

So far when you hover on the list item, it does highlight the corresponding map area, but how would I write it so that it hovered reciprocally?

I tried:

```
              $('.one, #one').hover(function(){     
                    $('#one, .one').attr("fill", "#213A46");
                    $(".info-one").fadeIn();
                },     
                function(){    
                    $('#one, .one').attr("fill", "#009A8B");   
                    $(".info-one").hide();
                });
```

and that did not seem to work. Any suggestions would be helpful. Here's a codepen of what I'm currently working on as well: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGzoMY

Comment: use custom data-* attributes. then, when in hover, use them as the selector like `$(this).attr('data-reciprocal')`

Comment: It looks like the issue is that the hover handler isn't even being run when you mouse over the polygon in the SVG.

Comment: Your codepen doesn't have `$("#one").hover()` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the state of an element, so you do have to change your `.region-list li:hover {` by `.region-list li:hover, .region-list li.hover {`.

Then you can add it in your JS, i.e. :

```
$('#four').hover(
    function() {     
        $('#four').attr("fill", "#213A46");
        $('.four').addClass('hover');
        $(".info-four").fadeIn();
    },     
    function() {    
        $('#four').attr("fill", "#3F6C80");
        $('.four').removeClass('hover');
        $(".info-four").hide(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. You will need to add a class like `.hover` to the element.

see: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-triggering-css-pseudo-selectors-like-hover

The way to trigger the hover on the li by hovering on the map is something like this:

```
$('#one').hover(function() {
  $('.one').trigger('mouseenter');
});
```

But to add the class you will do something like

```
$('#one').hover(function() {
  $('.one').addClass('hover');
});
```

Then remember to remove the class on mouseleave.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `hover` handler to the graphic that contains `#one`. Otherwise, when you mouse over the text inside the polygon, that's treated as leaving the polygon.

```
$('.one, g:has(#one)').hover(function() {
    $('#one').attr("fill", "#213A46");
    $('.region-list .one').css({
      backgroundColor: '#213a46',
      color: '#ffffff'
    });
    $(".info-one").fadeIn();
  },
  function() {
    $('#one').attr("fill", "#009A8B");
    $('.region-list .one').css({
      backgroundColor: 'inherit',
      color: 'inherit'
    });
    $(".info-one").hide();
  });
```

[Modified Codepen](http://codepen.io/barmar/pen/KpqapL)

I've only updated `#one`, the others are similar. It would be better to implement this using DRY methods where you find the reciprocal elements using data attributes, but I didn't bother with that rewrite.